# Do a goy (gentile), and/or an animal have ALL of these - Nefesh-Ruach-Neshama-Chaya-Yechida

Tags: soul

Can someone please give me a clear source as to whether or not a goy (gentile), and/or an animal have **ALL OF THESE FIVE** **Nefesh-Ruach-Neshama-Chaya-Yechida**. (More specifically looking for sources about the last two).

RELATED: [What are the five level of Neshama according to the Zohar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51113/what-are-the-five-level-of-neshama-according-to-the-zohar)

AND: [Do gentiles have neshamot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/do-gentiles-have-neshamot)

[PLEASE DON"T "DUPE" -  **I did not get clarity from either of the two**]

**DOES ANY SOURCE SAY ALL FIVE??**

If someone could show me exactly **where in the source the answer to my question** is stated I would be more than happy to check the original source myself. Saying "so-and-so discusses it" or even "so and so says that..." is not what I want. I want to be shown the words that say so.

Comment: You will not get any clarity as long as in Judaism, if you noticed, **NO TERM is defined**. The best way of understanding those terms is their practical implementation in Halachah (which is practically non-existent), for example "if you have Neshomah you can do X, but if you only have Nefesh you can do Y".Therefore your question is doomed and is a dupe of the ones you cite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do gentiles have neshamot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/do-gentiles-have-neshamot)

Comment: If you couldn't find a proper answer, you should offer a bounty to encourage people to give a better quality answer to those questions. The first seems to be a closer match to me.

Comment: Another problem is that unfortunately (all of) those terms (Nefesh, Ruach, Neshama) are used interchangeably EVERYWHERE - from the Torah, thru the Na"CH, Mishna, Talmud and all the Poskim. Therefore nobody who uses those terms can be truly trusted UNLESS he compares ALL of them. This IS a general problem with Judaism, but it needs a question on its own.

Comment: Probably not, but as long as they are not defined it is meaningless. I personally, like to ask מה נ"מ? What's נ"מ for you?

Comment: "וכל המקיים נפש אחת, מעלים עליו כאילו קיים עולם מלא" - what does it mean "a man is a whole world"? Too metaphoric...

Comment: @AlBerko ידיעת התורה הוא מצוה

Comment: I do share your frustration, but it in intristic to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty serious machlochet on this matter. Rabbi Hanan Balk provides a good treatment of the different answers arrived at by different sources here:

Audio version:

www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/744571/rabbi-hanan-balk/the-soul-of-a-jew-the-soul-of-a-non-jew-two-views/

PDF:
https://www.google.com.pe/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%252016%2520Balk.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwje0ZLOyZfcAhUkp1kKHStWCJoQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2F0T6qAJZCCwTTJ6m6MHHU

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Please point out where in the article is this specific point addressed. (whether a goy (gentile), and/or an animal have ALL of these - Nefesh-Ruach-Neshama-Chaya-Yechida).

Comment: How does this answer differ from [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9375/9643) to one of the linked questions? If it answers the question, this should be closed as a dupe. If not, it's a non-answer. (besides for being a link-only answer)

Comment: The rabbi cites sources ranging from "a goy and an animal have only a neshama" to "goys have the same souls as Jews". It's a complex matter, if it's of interest to you I would encourage you to read the article.

Comment: The answer is, basically, "there is no answer", @Ploni